# Java net HttpClient: React to timeout in async call

Tags: java, timeout, java-http-client

My goal is to react to the timeout in an asyncronius call of the HttpClient. I find many information on how to set the different timeouts but I do not find any information on how to react to the timeout if it occures.

The documentaton stating that:

> If the response is not received within the specified timeout then an HttpTimeoutException is thrown from HttpClient::send or HttpClient::sendAsync completes exceptionally with an HttpTimeoutException

But I don't know what exacly **completes exceptionally** mean.

### Example

In a sync call I can do (If the server behind the test URL don't answer):

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                 .uri(new URI("http://localhost:8080/api/ping/public"))
                                 .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                                 .build();
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

try {
  client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream());
} catch (HttpTimeoutException e) {
  System.out.println("Timeout");
}
```

What I want now is to do the same reaction to an async call like:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                 .uri(new URI("http://localhost:8080/api/ping/public"))
                                  .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                                  .build();
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();

client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream()).thenIfTimeout(System.out.println());
```

The last call is only a placeholder for the reaction to the timeout and does not exists. But how can I archive this?

Comment: 'I don't know what exacly "completes exceptionally" mean': it means it throws an exception, as the sentence you have partially quoted explicitly goes on to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do, there are at least three methods that you could use to take action when an exception occurs:

1. [CompletableFuture.exceptionally](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally(java.util.function.Function))
2. [CompletableFuture.whenComplete](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete(java.util.function.BiConsumer))
3. [CompletableFuture.handle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle(java.util.function.BiFunction))

- [1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally(java.util.function.Function)) allows you to return a result of the same type when an exception occurs
- [2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) allows you to trigger some action - and doesn't change the completion
  result or exception.
- [3](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle(java.util.function.BiFunction)) allows you to trigger some action, and change the type of the completion
  result or exception

By far the easiest would be to use [2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#whenComplete(java.util.function.BiConsumer)). Something like:

```
client.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofInputStream())
      .whenComplete((r,x) -> {
            if (x instanceof HttpTimeoutException) {
                 // do something
            }
       });
```